# Callable instead of Runnable so I do not need a catch

Tags: java, callable

I defined a Future in the following way:

```java
        Future<?>       future  = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
```

First I used (just playing to get to know the stuff):

```java
            future = service.submit(() -> {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                        System.out.println("Printing record old: " + i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // Ignore
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But I really did not like the try catch part, so I rewrote it to:

```java
            future = service.submit(() -> {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                        System.out.println("Printing record: " + i);
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }
                    return "Done";
                });
```

In this way a Callable is used instead of a Runnable and I do not need the catch. But I return an unused value.
Is it OK to do it in this way, or is there a better way?

Comment: If I were you, I'd stay away from `Thread.sleep` in the first place. If you need something to be done every N seconds, use a `Timer` or a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I only added the sleep to make the runtime of the thread longer. ;-)

Comment: @NathanHughes But I do not really return a value. I only do that so it becomes a Callable instead of a Runnable and I do not have to use the try catch I need to use when it is a Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of method syntax

[Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) `Runnable` class `run` method does not throw any exception so you need to handle any checked exception using try catch

```
void run()
```

[Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) But `Callable` class `call` method throws `Exception`, so either you can handle using `try catch` or leave for `JVM`

```
V call() throws Exception
```

Comment: That is what I mend: I make sure that it is a Callable so I do not have to use a try catch.

Comment: but i won't recommend to use `Callable` until you have requirement to return something @Cecil one line of code in try catch is not going to end world i believe

Comment: It is not one line, but three. And personally I find the code more beautiful. But if I was sure it was correct, I would not have asked. :-D

Answer (score 0):

When using `Callable`, if an exception is thrown you will get `ExecutionException` while calling future.get().

This exception will wrap the exception thrown by your callable, and can be accessed by `getCause()`

See more here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-runnable-callable

So you're not really avoiding any try/catch, just move it somewhere else (which makes sense- you need to handle it somewhere...)

Comment: At the moment I just do not want to use try catch, but your information is certainly interesting.